# In DDPM model, why authors subtract the largest value along j dimension of q*k values matrices?

Tags: transformer, diffusion-models

I have a question about a part of DDPM model code.
Below is the Attention class of DDPM model from this [website](https://huggingface.co/blog/annotated-diffusion). My questions is at the bottom.

```
class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, heads=4, dim_head=32):
        super().__init__()
        self.scale = dim_head**-0.5
        self.heads = heads
        hidden_dim = dim_head * heads
        self.to_qkv = nn.Conv2d(dim, hidden_dim * 3, 1, bias=False)
        self.to_out = nn.Conv2d(hidden_dim, dim, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        b, c, h, w = x.shape
        qkv = self.to_qkv(x).chunk(3, dim=1)
        q, k, v = map(
            lambda t: rearrange(t, "b (h c) x y -> b h c (x y)", h=self.heads), qkv
        )
        q = q * self.scale

        sim = einsum("b h d i, b h d j -> b h i j", q, k)
        sim = sim - sim.amax(dim=-1, keepdim=True).detach()
        attn = sim.softmax(dim=-1)

        out = einsum("b h i j, b h d j -> b h i d", attn, v)
        out = rearrange(out, "b h (x y) d -> b (h d) x y", x=h, y=w)
        return self.to_out(out)

class LinearAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, heads=4, dim_head=32):
        super().__init__()
        self.scale = dim_head**-0.5
        self.heads = heads
        hidden_dim = dim_head * heads
        self.to_qkv = nn.Conv2d(dim, hidden_dim * 3, 1, bias=False)

        self.to_out = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(hidden_dim, dim, 1), 
                                    nn.GroupNorm(1, dim))

    def forward(self, x):
        b, c, h, w = x.shape
        qkv = self.to_qkv(x).chunk(3, dim=1)
        q, k, v = map(
            lambda t: rearrange(t, "b (h c) x y -> b h c (x y)", h=self.heads), qkv
        )

        q = q.softmax(dim=-2)
        k = k.softmax(dim=-1)

        q = q * self.scale
        context = torch.einsum("b h d n, b h e n -> b h d e", k, v)

        out = torch.einsum("b h d e, b h d n -> b h e n", context, q)
        out = rearrange(out, "b h c (x y) -> b (h c) x y", h=self.heads, x=h, y=w)
        return self.to_out(out)
```

In `def forward` method, I know what this line does but don't understand why they do this:

```
sim = sim - sim.amax(dim=-1, keepdim=True).detach()
```

Why do they subtract `sim.amax(*)` values from `sim`?
Is this DDPM specific thing? I don't see this in the original Transformer.

I'm also referring to [this](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) website that explains Transformer.

Appreciate your help!